# Using custom environment variables in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, environment-variables

I need something like this:

```
SetEnv foo bar.baz
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^%{foo}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo/$1 [L]
```

**UPD:**

I have made as follows:

```
SetEnv HOSTNAME_ENV testsite
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^%{ENV:HOSTNAME_ENV}
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{ENV:HOSTNAME_ENV}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work. %{ENV:HOSTNAME_ENV} is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

This won't work, because `mod_rewrite` does not expand variables in test patterns. Consequently, your expression will attempt to match the regular expression `^%{foo}$`, not `^value_of_foo$`.

Additionally, the documentation for [`SetEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) also makes a special note about order-of-processing in relationship to `mod_rewrite`. This actually does come into play here, despite the rules being applied later in the request handling than the scenario they're describing there. If you don't perform a rewrite that causes an internal redirection before testing against the environment variable you set, it will be blank.

Assuming you set the variable correctly, a potential workaround is to do this, although I feel like it isn't foolproof:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{ENV:foo} ^([^#]+)#\1$
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the environment using rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=HOSTNAME_ENV:whatever.com]
```

This has also the advantage, that you are able to use RewriteCond.