# Setting environment specific htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess, environment-variables

So I usually want to set htaccess rules slightly differently based on what server it is on, eg live or development.

The ErrorDocument usually needs to be different, as well as some of the AddType and SetHandlers bits.

Is there any way I can make this a bit more dynamic and get it to auto detect based on the URL, then set a variable and have if conditionals further down in the htaccess?

Want to do this entirely from URL detection instead of setting parameters with apache please :)

Comment: What makes your URLs different between the development and live versions? Is it the host or the path?

Comment: @MathieuRodic both, the dev environment is on a different domain and not in root. eg www.livedomain.com and dev.otherdomain.com/devname/projectname

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't any way to set those things via some url detection. You can't make normal `if` conditions surrounding some of the things you want (`AddType SetHandlers` and `ErrorDocument`).

You could use env variables and mod rewrite but I don't think you'll like the end result. You'll have to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243048/881551) using `env|E=[!]VAR[:VAL]` syntax

If you were in the httpd.conf or vhost file you might be able to separate your different setups by using `<directory> sections </directory>`. But `Directory` is not allowed in htaccess.

Also I wouldn't do this in a production environment anyways since something could go wrong and I would think the detection is slower and not needed. Perhaps you may want to look into a build script you run to create/deploy your different setups for development/production depending on hostname and other factors.