# Understanding ... RewriteCond foo#%{ENV:bar} ^([^#]+)#\1$

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to understand what this rewrite condition exactly does:

```
RewriteCond foo#%{ENV:bar} ^([^#]+)#\1$
```

As stated in ["Using custom environment variables in .htaccess"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627771/1510754) this could be used as a workaround for testing environment variables in a rewrite condition - e.g. that "foo" equals the value of bar.

EDIT:

Thank you @miah for pointing out what the regex does. Although I still don't get why the variable can be tested in such a way, where it could not be tested directly.

UPDATE:

So when CondPattern does not evaluate the variable and it is evaluated in the TestString, why this does not work in comparison as bar is empty here:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:bar} ^foo$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clever bit here is that `\1` lets you reference a capture group from earlier in your regex.

1. `^` - from the beginning of the string you are checking (in this case `foo#%{ENV:bar}`)
2. `(` - start capture group
3. `[^#]+` - 1 or more characters that are not a `#`
4. `)` - end capture group
5. `#` - the character `#`
6. `\1` - the capture group from line 2-3
7. `$` - the end of the string.

**Update**

The issue is that the CondPattern part of RewriteCond does not evaluate environment variables, and it must be a perl compatible regular expression, or a string.

Comment: Thank you for exactly pointing out what the regex does, which is what I assumed it does ... but the part I don't get is, why the value of the variable is tested here although it could not be tested directly (as it would be empty).