# Variables within .htaccess redirects

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, setenv

I want to make reference to a variable called "foo" (with value "bar")

```
SetEnv foo bar
```

within a RewriteRule

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /{foo}.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

so that it *literally* reads as:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /bar.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

How is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using custom environment variables in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627411/using-custom-environment-variables-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky but can be done by combining `mod_setenvif` and `mod_rewrite`.

Use this code in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

SetEnvIf Host ^ foo=bar

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /%{ENV:foo}.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Can you explain what "SetEnvIf Host ^" does please? As I would like to conditionally set foo=bar on a given domain name. Eg. If domain1.com, set foo=bar1, else if domain2.com = foo=bar2

Comment: That is indeed possible with `SetEnvIf Host`. At present I just compare that with `^` (line start anchor) which means always set. But you can do: `SetEnvIf Host ^domain1 foo=domain1` OR `SetEnvIf Host ^domain2 foo=domain2` etc.